# How to fix the alignment issue of posts in this wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, w3-css

I am using w3school's w3css for this website and I have used the w3-col l6 m6 s12 for displaying the posts. It simply means that it will show 2 post side by side on large screen, same for the medium side display and only one covering all the 12 column on small screens.

But the posts are not aligning properly.

I tried adding the height property as auto but it's not working.

Check out this demo site that I have uploaded on my website so that you can see it in action.

http://wordpress.takshaksh.xyz/wp/

[image: website in live on web]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add below code in **style.css**

```
div.w3-row-padding {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

or add new class in **w3-row-padding** like **col_wrap** and apply below style

```
.col_wrap {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col_wrap:after,
.col_wrap:before { display:none;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's fixed now. I never expected that fast solution delivery. Can you tell me what the above properties are doing !!

Comment: you are welcome, above property is new in css for display elements. if you use " bootstrap 4 " framework for css than above properties already in that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this CSS your parent container on `w3-col l6 m6 s12`

```
.w3-row-padding{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by only having 2 items per `<div class="w3-row-padding w3-row">`.